# How do I Process This String?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have some results in one of my tables and the results vary, each; represents multiple entries in one column which I need to split out.

Here is my SQL and the results:

```
    select REGEXP_COUNT(value,';') as cnt,
    description
    from mytable;
```

```
1   {Managed By|xBoss}{xBoss xBoss Number|X0910505569}{Time 
Requested|2009-04-15 20:47:11.0}{Time Arrived|2009-04-15 21:46:11.0};   
1   {Managed By|Modern Management}{xBoss Number|}{Time Requested|2009-04- 
16 14:01:29.0}{Time Arrived|2009-04-16 14:44:11.0}; 
2   {Managed By|xBoss}{xBoss Number|X091480092}{Time Requested|2009-05-28 
08:58:41.0}{Time Arrived|};{Managed By|Jims Allocation}{xBoss xBoss 
Number|}{Time Requested|}{Time Arrived|};
```

Desired output:

```
R1:
Managed By: xBoss
Time Requested:2009-10-19 07:53:45.0
Time Arrived: 2009-10-19 07:54:46.0

R2:
Managed By:Own Arrangements
Number: x5876523
Time Requested: 2009-10-19 07:57:46.0
Time Arrived:

R3:
Managed By: xBoss
Time Requested:2009-10-19 08:07:27.0
```

```
    select   
    SPLIT_PART(description, '}', 1), 
    SPLIT_PART(description, '}', 2), 
    SPLIT_PART(description, '}', 3), 
    SPLIT_PART(description, '}', 4), 
    SPLIT_PART(description, '}', 5) 
    as description_with_tag from mytable;
```

This is ok when the count is `1`, but when there are multiple `;` in the description it doesn't give me the results.

Is it possible to put this into an array based on the count?

Comment: What output are you wanting to achieve? Do you want to obtain `{Managed By|xBoss}`, or just `Managed By|xBoss`? Or perhaps just `xBoss`? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details. Also, why are you counting semicolons in `value` but showing `description`?

Comment: John, I just want to retrieve the results xBoss, The term will Managed By will always be the same, but xBoss will frequently change. The semicolons determine how many incidents there has been for one event. The select REGEXP_COUNT(value,';')  will tell the the amount.

Comment: I am still confused. Could you please edit your question to show the output you would like for each input line? Please provide multiple examples.

Comment: This is the result of the query in it's raw form.
{Managed By|xBoss}{Number|}{Time Requested|2009-10-19 07:53:45.0}{Time Arrived|2009-10-19 07:54:46.0};{Managed By|Own Arrangements}{Number|x5876523}{Time Requested|2009-10-19 07:57:46.0}{Time Arrived|};{Managed By|xBoss}{Number|}{Time Requested|2009-10-19 08:07:27.0}{Time Arrived|};

Comment: This is how I want to manipulate the results for my ETL

    R1
    Managed By: xBoss
    Number:
    Time Requested:2009-10-19 07:53:45.0
    Time Arrived: 2009-10-19 07:54:46.0;

    R2
    Managed By:Own Arrangements
    Number: x5876523
    Time Requested: 2009-10-19 07:57:46.0
    Time Arrived:;

    R3
    Managed By:xBoss
    Number:
    Time Requested:2009-10-19 08:07:27.0
    Time Arrived:;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's worth pointing out that data in this type of format cannot take advantage of all the benefits that Redshift can offer. Amazon Redshift is a columnar database that can provide amazing performance when data is stored in appropriate columns. However, selecting specific text from a text field will always perform poorly.

Therefore, my main advice would be to **pre-process the data into normal rows and columns** so that Redshift can provide you the best capabilities.

However, to answer your question, I would recommend making a **Scalar User-Defined Function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_extract_curly (s TEXT, key TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
STABLE
AS $$
  # List of items in {brackets}
  items = s[1:-1].split('}{')

  # Dictionary of Key|Value from items
  entries = {i.split('|')[0]: i.split('|')[1] for i in items}

  # Return desired value
  return entries.get(key, None)

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

I loaded sample data with:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    description TEXT
);

INSERT INTO foo values('{Managed By|xBoss}{xBoss xBoss Number|X0910505569}{Time Requested|2009-04-15 20:47:11.0}{Time Arrived|2009-04-15 21:46:11.0};');
INSERT INTO foo values('{Managed By|Modern Management}{xBoss Number|}{Time Requested|2009-04-16 14:01:29.0}{Time Arrived|2009-04-16 14:44:11.0};');
INSERT INTO foo values('{Managed By|xBoss}{xBoss Number|X091480092}{Time Requested|2009-05-28 08:58:41.0}{Time Arrived|};{Managed By|Jims Allocation}{xBoss xBoss Number|}{Time Requested|}{Time Arrived|};');
```

Then I tested it with:

```
SELECT
  f_extract_curly(description, 'Managed By'),
  f_extract_curly(description, 'Time Requested')
FROM foo
```

and got the result:

```
xBoss               2009-04-15 20:47:11.0
Modern Management   2009-04-16 14:01:29.0
xBoss
```

It doesn't know how to handle lines that have the same field specified twice (with semi-colons between). You did not provide enough sample input and output lines for me to figure out what you wanted in such situations, but feel free to tweak the code for your requirements.

Comment: This is excellent! sometimes I get an error message
list index out of range. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information
How can I return a null value if it doesn't find anything?

Comment: SELECT name,
       REGEXP_COUNT(sep_val,';'),
       f_extract_curly(SPLIT_PART(value,';',1),'Managed By'),
       f_extract_curly(SPLIT_PART(value,';',2),'Time Requested')
    FROM foo;

This seems to work, but I do get [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: I've edited the `return` statement, so it should return `None` if there is no such entry. I'm not sure if Redshift converts the Python `None` into an SQL `NULL`, so please test it and let us know!

Comment: That's Awesome John... Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no array data type in Redshift. There are 2 options:

1) First `split_part` by `';'`, then union results separately for every index of the first `split_part` output, then `split_part` results by `'}'` and finally get what you need.

2) Create a Python UDF and process these strings with Python. I guess this is the best solution for your use case.

3) Transform your data outside Redshift. From your data structure it seems like it's much better to process it before copying to Redshift, unnesting the arrays into rows and extracting keys from your objects into columns.